# Posing a bone is causing the mesh to squash and stretch. [Solved]

Tags: armature, scale

I'm trying to pose a bone to rotate an object. For some reason the rotation is also causing the object to scale itself strangely. I've included two images, the first is the object at it's "default" size and the second image is the bone rotated 90 degrees.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Select your mesh, hit Ctrl+A and apply location, rotation and scale.

Comment: Of course it's that simple lol.
Thanks man

Comment: Yep. It's always the simple things. Make sure to use it on every object you create, regardless of its transforms or its purpose. Applying transforms solve a lot of problems with other things, too.